# Optional generic types not being inferred

Tags: typescript, next.js, typescript-generics

I'm creating a wrapper to handle NextJS API requests in Typescript. However, I have a type error when I want to pass a single type for one of the generic types in the function.

I've created a simple function to show this error. The example below passes 2 parameters and changes parameter `bar` to an array. `foo`'s type should be `unknown` unless explicitly defined. `bar`'s type should always be inferred. When generic types are not defined explicitly, the function's return type is inferred correctly (line 6).

However, when generic type `Foo` is set to number, a type error appears because type `Bar` is automatically set as undefined and is not inferred from the parameter's type anymore (line 9).

Line 12 shows how you are forced to define all the generic types if you want to define at least 1 of them.

[image]

```
function test<Foo = unknown, Bar = undefined>(foo: Foo, bar: Bar) {
    return { foo, bar: [bar] }
}

// Works - Return type { foo: number; bar: string[] }
const a = test(10, 'bar')

// Does not work - Return type { foo: number; bar: undefined[] }
const b = test<number>(10, 'bar')

// Works - Return type { foo: number; bar: string[] }
const c = test<number, string>(10, 'bar')
```

Is there a workaround to optionally define a generic type while not manually defining the others?

Comment: can you add code snippet inside of image please

Comment: @Lakshya Added the snippet just below the image

Comment: I suppose the error happens, Bar takes it's default value which is undefined. So either you define all the types or let compiler let do it's job, moreover why you're using the default type as 'undefined'

Comment: @Lakshya In the real function, `Foo` represents the response data, which sometimes I want to explicitly define for more typesafety. `Bar` represents the input data from the request's body. The input type should be automatically inferred based on the zod schema I pass when calling the handler.

If you wanna check the handler function: https://pastebin.com/G2N9xPNP
Line 36 has a type error because it thinks that `input` should be undefined.

Comment: Function inference is all or nothing, you either let TS infer all type args or you specify all of them (with some coming from defaults). There is no partial function inference dispite several propsals toadd it

Comment: Without partial type argument inference (e.g., [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)) you have to work around it.  One common workaround is *currying*, as shown [in this TS Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m0b5Ow).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply so I'm notified)

Comment: @jcalz Ty for your response. I guess that currying solves this problem. However, I don't wanna overcomplicated myself so I will be defining both types every time I need to define one of them. If you want you can write the answer and I will give it as valid for others that have the same question I had. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript currently has no direct support for *partial* [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument inference.  If you have a generic function with multiple type parameters, like `declare function foo<T, U>(t: T, u: U): F<T, U>;` then you can either manually specify all of them like `foo<X, Y>(x, y)`, or you can get the compiler to infer all of them like `foo(x, y)`.  You cannot specify some but get inference for the others, as in `foo<X>(x, y)`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) for the relevant feature request.

And no, [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) like `declare function foo<T = A, U = B>(t: T, u: U): F<T, U>` do *not* give you this functionality.  If there's a default, then specifying some of the parameters gives you the default for the ones you leave out.  It does not infer anything.  Maybe in the future there will be some syntax like `declare function foo<T = infer, U = infer>(t: T, u: T): F<T, U>` which allows defaults to be pressed into service for partial type argument inference.  But for now, it's just not part of the language.

---

Until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#26242 is implemented, there are workarounds.  The most common one I use is [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).  Since each generic function call requires you to specify all the type arguments or infer all the type arguments, you can emulate partial inference by splitting the single function call into multiple.  So you can make `const fooCurry: <T,>(t: T): <U,>(u: U) => F<T, U>` or the like.

For your example code, it looks like:

```
const testCurry = <F,>(foo: F) => <B,>(bar: B) => test(foo, bar);
```

And then the calls become

```
const b = testCurry<number>(10)('bar');
/* const b: { foo: number;  bar: string[]; } */
```

Where you successfully specify that `F` is `number` but let the compiler infer that `B` is `string`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgGKILyLgDWYcA7mADSIBC+hYAJisDGCowHwAUwccALkTZqAIwCGAJyE0AlIgDeAKESrEklFBCSkCxHzhipQgNoTJAXUQBfJbaUB6B4gDqcSUTSIAtIgBKmtpIUACeAA4oivr8QmAgALaiKJIA3IjmQhiSbADmJla2EAgYiOL0qBjcAIwADNQA5Ob1skqOzm4eXr4BWjrI4ZF6BrEJSanpxohZufk2SkVgJRDl6FhxicnU02A5PLUNTS2tCyUVUADC2pIh9DiUPMPC8niciJg099wZtM+vZ7z8IySWQpebFKDpFYYS6Sa6YdZjPY1WTcRpSZqghwAKkQJwhoiEQxiiARyTSE2kUyg2R2+TS1kQWIcSiAA)